# How to get compose view work with a InlineViewStrategy

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to get a conpose view going in a InlineViewStrategy.

The simple , "hard coded" table view in a custom template works in the context of a higher level div tag ("x_content") as represented in the Vendor Spend for Maintain below passed into InlineViewStrategy

```
    '                   <table class="" style="width:100%">',
    '                      <tr>',
    '                         <th style="width:37%;">',
    '                            <p>Top 5</p>',
    '                         </th>',
    '                         <th>',
    '                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">',
    '                              <p class="">Vendor</p>',
    '                            </div>',
    '                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">',
    '                              <p class="">Progress</p>',
    '                            </div>',
    '                          </th>',
    '                       </tr>',
    '                       <tr>',
        '                          <td>',
        '                              <canvas id="canvas1" height="140" width="140" style="margin: 15px 10px 10px 0"></canvas>',
        '                          </td>',
        '                          <td>',
        '                             <table class="tile_info">',
        '                                 <tr>',
        '                                   <td>',
        '                                        <p><i class="fa fa-square blue"></i>Vendor 1 </p>',
        '                                   </td>',
        '                                   <td>30%</td>',
        '                                 </tr>',
    '                              </table>',
        '                           </td>',
    '                        </tr>',
    '                    </table>',
```

[image: The data in Vendor Spend Maintain]

If I try to put the same content (verbatim wrapped with a template) in an html file (ie. test-view.html) and do a compose on test-view.html replacing the HTML with compose AND PASSING THAT to InLoneViewStrategy,  I get a a blank screen

```
    <compose view="./test-view.html"> </compose>
```

I get on the console, "Unhandled rejection Error: Load timeout for modules: template-registry-entry!test-view.html,text!test-view.html". Is there somewhere else that I should be putting this test-view.html? Or am I missing something?

```
    to be more specific
 [
 ' ... '
 '            <div class="x_content">           ',
 '       HTMLTABLE STUFF ',
 '            </div>                            ' 
 ' ...         ].join( " ")
```

get replaced by

```
   [
   ' ... '
   '            <div class="x_content">           ',
   '  <compose view="./test-view.html"> </compose>',
   '            </div>                            ' 
   ' ...         ].join( " ")
```

in custom template which is then passed to InlineViewStrategy

Thanks, in advance your help.

Answer (score 0):

test-view.html has to be in the relevant directory... in this case , at src level